# Why are these 2 stings in C not equal?

Tags: c

I have created a substring from a string, but the equality condition doesn't seem to hold when checked with the exact same string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
      char  per[] = "wefgq retc";
      int c = 0;
      char sub[10];
      while (c < 4) {
        sub[c] = per[c];
        c++;
    }
    sub[c] = '\0';

    char  ler[] = "wefg";

    printf("%s,\n", sub);
    if (ler == sub) {printf("same");}
    else {printf("not same");}
}
```

The output of this code when compiled and executed is-

```
wefg,
not same
```

can somebody please explain why this is happening? Is there something wrong with the way I have created the string, like the '\0' character?
**Edit-** I used strcmp() instead of == but still got the same result.

Comment: To compare strings in C you need to use a dedicated function like `strcmp`

Comment: To elaborate on @EugeneSh. 's comment, `if (ler == sub)` is not comparing the contents of the arrays, but rather the addresses of the first elements of each array due to [pointer decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3282436).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not be compared directly like `if(str1==str2)`, as this will only compare the [decayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) pointers of the character arrays with each other. It will not compare the actual string contents. You need to use the [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function to compare the actual string contents.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        char str1[] = "abcd", str2[] = "abCd", str3[] = "abcd";
        int result;
    
        // comparing strings str1 and str2
        result = strcmp(str1, str2);
        printf("strcmp(str1, str2) = %d\n", result);
    
        // comparing strings str1 and str3
        result = strcmp(str1, str3);
        printf("strcmp(str1, str3) = %d\n", result);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Of course there are strings in C.

Comment: now is it fine ? @Crowman

Comment: @Crowman, just to add some pedantry: There are no string *datatype* in standard c, only a string *convention*.

Comment: In [§7.1.1 ¶1 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1), a string is defined in the following way: `"A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character."`

Comment: Thanks, resloved mow!

Comment: @HAL9000: What Andreas said - a string is not a "convention" in C, it's a concrete thing with a formal definition. It's not a type, certainly, but that's a long way from saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Crowman, yes, it is wrong to say that strings doesn't exist in c. And while the claim that there are strings in c is absolute correct, some clarification may be helpful to programmers that are more used to other languages.